# php echo not working but declared variable in included php file

Tags: php, echo

files are init.php which is included in user_settings.php

below is the code

```
## init.php ##
<?php
session_start();
require 'database/connect.php';
require 'functions/users.php';
require 'functions/general.php';

if (logged_in() === true) {
    $session_user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $user_data = user_data($session_user_id, 'user_id', 'username', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email');
}
$errors = array();
?>
```

### and user_setting.php

```
<?php 
include 'core/init.php';
include 'includes/overall/header.php';
echo $user_data['first_name'];
include 'includes/overall/footer.php';
?>
```

I can't see any reason why I cannot echo from the $user_data?

probably someone with more experience will be able to tell straight away! any and all help will be greatly appreciated!

Ryan

Comment: `logged_in()` does not return `true` and therefore `$user_data` is never set would be my guess. Try `var_dump($user_data);` to see if it is set. Also you should turn on PHP warnings and notices. Another source of error could be the function `user_data()`. Make sure it does not return `null` or an empty string.

Comment: Do `var_dump($user_data)`. If it's empty then you cannot echo your field. Find out if it is set, your user_data function could be failing, your `logged_in` could be failing, etc etc. Do some basic debugging. add some `var_dump`s, check if the fucntions are called, etc.

Comment: I used the var_dump($user_data) it returned as null.

however when i used var_dump($session_user_id) i recieve string '1' (length=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can Try this one

1) First remove "## init.php ##" in the top of init.php file. Since, No string even space should not be there before session_start() function

2) check user_data() function, that return the expected data's.

Comment: Thanks very much!

I had left out


return $data;